# Type.GetType() doesn't work for non-native types?

Tags: c#, gettype

I tried getting the type of `UnityEngine.Vector3` using `Type.GetType()` but its returning `NULL`. It works fine for native types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to specify the assembly in which this type is located as well if the type is situated in a different assembly:

```
var type = Type.GetType("UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine", true);
```

Comment: I save the type using this:

string typeName = vector3Value.GetType().ToString();

And then later on access it using Type.GetType(typeName); Should I save it using vector3Value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName? That will work but it generates a little longer value. Anyway I can save the typeName in a string but value has to be short.

Comment: @farooqaaa. It will give you `Type`, not a `string`. That won't even compile! **Edit:** Yes you need the `AssemblyQualifiedName`. See the docs in my answer.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot the ".ToString()" part. Edit: Can't edit my last comment. "Is there any way I can save the typeName in a string but with a shorter value? Currently it saves CultureInfo etc"

Comment: @farooqaaa. I suggest you open a new thread with your question. asking too much questions in the comments causes a mess and unhelpul question-answers. darin, I hope you are not angry for messing your answer with the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Assembly if it's not a "nativa type" or inside the calling Assembly

Read this:

> If typeName includes the namespace but not the assembly name, this method searches only the calling object's assembly and Mscorlib.dll, in that order. If typeName is fully qualified with the partial or complete assembly name, this method searches in the specified assembly. If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required.

**typeName** (the parameter of `Type.GetType(string type)`)

> Type: System.String
>   **The assembly-qualified name of the type to get**. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.
>   The syntax is like this:

```
var type = Type.GetType("UnityEngine.Vector3, AssemblyName");
```